# Event Receiver when document body/content is updated

Tags: event-receivers

What event receiver is triggered when the content of an existing Word document is updated/changed?  ItemUpdated works when the properties on the document are updated (e.g. changing a content type column on the item/document causes ItemUpdated to get called).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread was very helpful: [file rename](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-ZA/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/b687d897-f04f-493d-80c3-35d804b6cef4)

Answer (score 0):

Both the ItemUpdating and ItemUpdated event receivers get called when you update a document in a document library.

Comment: The event receiver works when I update properties on the document.  I am updating/changing the document name (i.e. item["Name"]).  Is this even possible if the Word document is open?  When I "upload" the document the code in the event receiver works fine.  The document name is changed by the event receiver on uploaded documents.  Would the same code/event receiver work if the document exists in the document library, I click to open it, and Word launches.  When I hit "save" in Word I am expecting the event receiver to be called and, therefore, the document name to be updated/changed.

Answer (score 0):

The event receiver should work even when you update any changes to the corresponding documents as the code is written under Item Updating. You can check it by enabling the Versioning of the documents. Try to check weather the version of the document changes when you update every time. If version changes... then its sure that event receiver is fired there...